# Django - после каждого третьего элемента ставить BR

Tags: django

Всем привет!
У меня есть кусок кода

```
{% for product in products %}
<li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">{% render_product product %}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

который выводит по очереди нужный товар. Мне нужно после каждого третьего товара вставить перевод строки

```
<br class="clr" />
```

Чтобы товары не съезжали, я в Django новичек, жду поддержки)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно также использовать тэг cycle

```
{% for product in products %}
<li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">{% render_product product %}</li>
{% cycle '' '' '<br class="clr" />' %}
{% endfor %}
```

в результате каждая третья итерация будет со вставкой br

Answer (score 2):

Если текущая итерация делится на 3 без остатка, то выводим тег:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">{% render_product product %}</li>
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}<br class="clr" /> {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```